# Can't solve Python argparse error 'object has no attribute'

Tags: python, argparse

When I run this code I get

```
AttributeError: 'ArgumentParser' object has no attribute 'max_seed'
```

Here's the code

```
import argparse
import ConfigParser

CFG_FILE='/my.cfg'

# Get command line arguments
args = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args.add_argument('verb', choices=['new'])
args.add_argument('--max_seed', type=int, default=1000)
args.add_argument('--cmdline')
args.parse_args()

if args.max_seed:
    pass

if args.cmdline:
    pass
```

My source file is called "fuzz.py"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should first initialize the parser and arguments and only then get the actual arguments from `parse_args()` (see [example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#example) from the docs):

```
import argparse
import ConfigParser

CFG_FILE='/my.cfg'

# Get command line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('verb', choices=['new'])
parser.add_argument('--max_seed', type=int, default=1000)
parser.add_argument('--cmdline')

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.max_seed:
    pass

if args.cmdline:
    pass
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `argparse` parsed arguments inside another class (somewhere you do `self.args = parser.parse_args()` ), you might need to explicitly tell your lint parser to ignore `Namespace` type checking. As told by [@frans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668622/frans) at [Avoid Pylint warning E1101: 'Instance of .. has no .. member' for class with dynamic attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38976257/2928168)
:

> Just to provide the answer that works for me now - as [The
>   Compiler][1] suggested you can add a rule for the problematic class in
>   your projects `.pylintrc`:
>
> ```
> [TYPECHECK]
> ignored-classes=Namespace
> ```
>
> [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2085149/the-compiler