# Avoid Pylint warning E1101: 'Instance of .. has no .. member' for class with dynamic attributes

Tags: python, dynamic, pylint

Imagine a function which *dynamically* adds attributes to an object using `setattr`. The reason for doing so is that I want to map some external structure (e.g. a given parameter tree) to an object:

```
my_object = SomeClass()
apply_structure(my_object, some_descriptor)
my_object.device1.enabled = True
```

Technically this works but of course Pylint rightly complains about 'device1' being not a member of `SomeClass`.

I could disable the warning but that would be bad (because I still want to get the warning in all cases when the attribute does not exist because of misspelling, etc).

Is there a common and legal (Pylint-proof) way to dynamically add members to an object that not leads to warnings?

Alternatively: Can I disable Pylint for just one *object* rather than a line/block/file?

**Explanation**:

You might wonder why I should equip an object with member attributes dynamically when I plan to access these attributes in a hard-coded way later.

The reason is: I have a dynamic part of the program (where the decoration happens) and a static part which is *specialized* for a certain *scenario*. So I **could** also create a static class for this scenario but that would be overkill in a lot of situations.

The following *specialized* code might allow access to some parameter of a device which might be attached to some bus:

```
class MyDeviceHandler:
   on_get_some_subtree_element(self):
      return _some_internal_value
   on_set_some_subtree_element(self, value):
      _some_internal_value = value

dev = MyDeviceHandler()

decorate_object_with_device_structure(dev, 'some/attached/device')

dev.some.subtree.element = 5      # <--- will call the set-callback
x = dev.some.subtree.element      # <--- will call the get-callback
```

So the structure behind `'some/attached/device'` might be arbitrary and very complex and I don't want to reproduce it in a class structure.

One way to get rid of this warning would be to create/access a `dict` based tree:

```
dev['some']['subtree']['element'] = 5
```

But this is harder to write and not nice to read - I would only do this to quieten Pylint.

Comment: My question is, if you know in advance the structure that you would like to access, why not define that structure explicitly in the first place?

Comment: That's exactly the problem. I don't know it. Actually I read a structure from a device property tree (which can be anything) and I build a Python object. I'll elaborate on this a bit further in the question..

Comment: You can set the `generated-members` or `ignored-classes` [options for pylint](https://docs.pylint.org/features.html#id28) (on the commandline, or under `[TYPECHECK]` in a `.pylintrc`)

Comment: @TheCompiler You should add that as an answer. `generated-members` was the solution to my use-case. I had an `options` singleton that multiple modules would add options (and default values) to. The options singleton encapsulated behavior relating to parsing command-line options. But the names and defaults for the options were still organized according to the modules that use those specific options.

Comment: `--generated-members=MyEnum` mutes the error `Instance of 'str' has no 'value' memberpylint(no-member)`

Answer (score 80, accepted):

*Used when an object (variable, function, …) is accessed for a non-existent member.*

*False positives: This message may report object members that are created dynamically, but exist at the time they are accessed.*

A commentator mentions that it can be disabled on a single line at the top of the file with `# pylint: disable=no-member`.  I also found that you can use `# pylint: disable=E1101` based on [this reddit entry](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/87b1l6/vs_code_pylint_e1101_error/).

**IMPORTANT - EDIT from Comments**

Not an ideal solution, since you'd be disabling the check for all code in the file.

You can add it to the end of the line where the error is so that only the error in that line is disabled. This way you don't have to disable it for the rest of the code.

Comment: Concise and comprehensive solution. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: I'd argue this is not an ideal solution, since you'd be disabling the check for all code in the file.  This is a valuable check which catches a lot of real problems.  And you'd need to do that for every file that uses the class.

The ideal solution would be for pylint to ignore that error with the one class only.

Comment: You can add it to the end of the line where the error is so that only the error in that line is disabled. This way you don't have to disable it for the rest of the code

Answer (score 63):

An answer that works for me: As [The Compiler suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990313/avoid-pylint-warning-e1101-instance-of-has-no-member-for-class-with-dyn#comment59658991_35990313), you can add a rule for the problematic class in your projects `.pylintrc`:

```
[TYPECHECK]
ignored-classes=Fysom,MyClass
```

Comment: Doesn't work unless you add `str` to it... which seems broken

Comment: this is more a hack than a real solution because it ignores the problem instead of tackling it but I guess it works

Answer (score 18):

Pylint gives this type of errors on two cases ([reference](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:e1101)):

- Used when an object (variable, function, …) is accessed for a
  non-existent member.
- False positives: This message may report object members that are
  created dynamically, but exist at the time they are accessed.

As this error is identified as an E1101 error, you can solve the issue by adding the following line in your code.

```
# pylint: disable=E1101
```

Comment: Downvote. Copy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54156144/131160).

Answer (score 10):

I was able to avoid this warning by adding the `__getattr__` method to my class, which Python calls when an attribute is not found on an object.  Although definitely not the cleanest solution, it worked for my particular use-case as Pylint considers the object valid.

```
import warnings
class AppConfiguration(object):
    ...
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        ''' Will only get called for undefined attributes '''
        warnings.warn('No member "%s" contained in settings config.' % name)
        return ''
```

More information about the `__getattr__` method can be [found here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__).

Comment: This worked for me. As long as you know what are you doing this does the trick.

Answer (score 7):

Try this! My problem was solved!

Pylint doesn't understand the Django's dynamic field. Thus, we need to teach what the Django is to Pylint.

#### For Visual Studio Code in Windows 10

```
pip install pylint-django
cd your_project_folder
code . // Run Visual Studio Code
```

Install extension for Python, Django Snippets, Django Template in Visual Studio Code.

Open [`.vscode/settings.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file) in Visual Studio Code and add:

```javascript
{
   "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
   "python.linting.enabled": true,
   "python.pythonPath": "venv\\Scripts\\python.exe",
   "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
       "--load-plugins",
       "pylint_django"
   ],
}
```

Comment: Why are you relating this to Django?

Comment: just adding "python.linting.pylintArgs":[ " --load-plugins"] was sufficient for me. This seems unrelated to django hence the downvote.

Comment: Re *".vscode/settings.json"*: Presumably ***not*** on Windows? What platform was it tested on?

Comment: Note that the setting is now "pylint.args" (not "python.linting.pylintArgs").

Answer (score 1):

Another possible reason for getting the `no-member` is, that the `self` argument of the `__init__()` method of this class is missing:

Wrong:

```py
class foo:
    def __init__(bar):
        self.bar = bar
```

Right:

```py
class foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
```

Application code to get the `no-member` warning:

```py
x = foo('bar')
print(x.bar) # <-- this line will be the reported error line
```

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to add to this answer, since I'd prefer if there was an explicit way to do this with Pylint.

There is a hack around solution that is working (at least as of Pylint 2.7.4).  In this example code, I use a "getattr" null-op to prevent Pylint from thinking it knows anything about the object.  Obviously, something this simple might not continue working going forward, but I like the fact that you can control which exact things you want Pylint to ignore without having to touch anything other than source file, and without having to disable the check globally throughout the source file.

```
class MyClass():
    """an empty class"""

myc = MyClass()
print(myc.hello_world)  # Pylint no-member
myc = globals()['myc']
print(myc.hello_world)  # No error flagged

class MyDeviceHolder1():
    """a device holder class"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.devices = MyClass()

mdh1 = MyDeviceHolder1()
print(mdh1.devices.hello_world)  # Pylint no-member

class MyDeviceHolder2():
    """a device holder class"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.devices = MyClass()
        self.devices = getattr(self, 'devices')

mdh2 = MyDeviceHolder2()
print(mdh2.devices.hello_world)  # No error flagged
print(mdh2.devixes.hello_world)  # Pylint no-member
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, just installing *pylint-django* solved the issue:

```
pip install pylint-django
```

Comment: why mixing to django?

Comment: @Kots because it fixes E1101 being raised when using `self.client` from `django.test.TestCase` if you try to access dynamic things like `status_code` or `json` from the `get` or `post` response.