# How do i create a protobuf3 Timestamp in python?

Tags: python, timestamp, protocol-buffers

I see that there is a Timestamp object but it doesn't seem to work. 
Using Python 3.6

```
$ pip install protobuf3
```

In python:

```
from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp
timestamp = Timestamp()
timestamp.GetCurrentTime()
```

Nothing is returned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "nothing is returned"? What happens if you add `print(timestamp)` after the third line? Note that `timestamp.GetCurrentTime()` changes the value of the `timestamp` object, rather than returning a new object.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this! I think I had an environment problem.

Answer (score 19):

ARRGGG I think there was a virtual env problem. It works now!

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp
>>> timestamp = Timestamp()
>>> timestamp.GetCurrentTime()
>>> print(timestamp)
seconds: 1521497361
nanos: 600455000

>>>timestamp
seconds: 1521497361
nanos: 600455000
```

Comment: is it mandatory though to initialize the variable a priori and then call the GetCurrentTime, can't it happen somehow in a one-liner on the fly ? to be include in a RPC message at once like timestamp = timestamp.Timestamp().GetCurrentTime()

Comment: although this code is executed normally in command line, in vs code this message appears: "Instance of 'Timestamp' has no 'GetCurrentTime' member"
What could it be ?

Comment: my case was discussed here, a false positive and suppressing the warning
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990313/avoid-pylint-warning-e1101-instance-of-has-no-member-for-class-with-dyn

Answer (score 9):

The only two args of constructing a protobuf Timestamp are seconds and nanos. They are defined as the seconds from the Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00). So we can do:

```
import datetime
from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp

t = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
seconds = int(t)
nanos = int(t % 1 * 1e9)

proto_timestamp = Timestamp(seconds=seconds, nanos=nanos)
```

Answer (score 9):

Simple example:

```
message Data {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp tstamp = 1;
}
```

setting value:

```
message.tstamp.FromDatetime(datetime.datetime.now())
```

printing received message:

```
tstamp {
    seconds: 1648070801
    nanos: 661005000
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
timestamp.GetCurrentTime()
```

Actually this method fills in the current time rather than getting the current time.

Check documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#timestamp)