# Disable pylint warning E1101 when using enums

Tags: python, django, enums, pylint

I recently came across [this article](http://anthonyfox.io/2017/02/choices-for-choices-in-django-charfields/#option-3) by Anthony Fox which shows how to use enums to create the choice set in django CharFields, which I thought was pretty neat.

Basically, you create a subclass of Enum:

```
from enum import Enum

class ChoiceEnum(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return tuple((x.name, x.value) for x in cls)
```

Which can then be used in your models like so:

```
from .utils import ChoiceEnum

class Car(models.Model):
    class Colors(ChoiceEnum):
        RED = 'red'
        WHITE = 'white'
        BLUE = 'blue'

    color = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=Colors.choices(), default=Colors.RED.value)

red_cars = Car.objects.filter(color=Car.Colors.RED.value)
```

However, pylint throws a warning whenever you try to access the enum value (`Colors.RED.value`)

`E1101:Instance of 'str' has no 'value' member`

Is there a way to avoid / disable this warning for every instance of ChoiceEnum?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990313/avoid-pylint-warning-e1101-instance-of-has-no-member-for-class-with-dyn) only works on the subclass of `ChoiceEnum`, not `ChoiceEnum` itself.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990313/avoid-pylint-warning-e1101-instance-of-has-no-member-for-class-with-dyn?noredirect=1&lq=1 might solve your issue

Comment: I think the proper solution is for pylint to recognize `Enum`s.  File an enhancement request/bug report with them.

Comment: @VitorBaptista I linked to that answer in my question, it only works on subclasses of ChoiceEnum (and there are a lot of them). If possible, I'd like a more global solution (other than disabling the warning entirely).

Comment: Turns out this issue has already been opened with pylint: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/533

Answer (score 2):

Since the [issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/533) is still open, we can use the following workaround

```
from .utils import ChoiceEnum

class Car(models.Model):
    class Colors(ChoiceEnum, Enum):
        RED = 'red'
        WHITE = 'white'
        BLUE = 'blue'

    color = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=Colors.choices(), default=Colors.RED.value)
```

This doesn't create the pylint error now

Comment: It took me some time to find the solution. It's in the Colors class inheritance. Anyway, I couldn't make it work. I'd say the problem is not related with the inheritance at all.