# Instance of 'DateTimeField' has no 'strftime' member

Tags: django, django-models

I was following a book "Django 2 By Example". But, stuck at here.
I tried searching over the internet , but didn't get anything specific.

The  **models.py** >>

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset()\
        .filter(status='published')


class post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=126)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=126, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager() #default manager
    published = PublishedManager() #custom manager

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blogposts:post_detail',
                        args=[
                            self.publish.year,
                            self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                            self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                            self.slug ])
```

[This](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-extract-the-year-from-a-DateTimeField-in-Django.php) tutorial is following the doing the same. But i'm getting an error from pylint that `E1101: Instance of 'DateTimeField' has no 'strftime' member`
 What am i missing?

Comment: similar to[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990313/avoid-pylint-warning-e1101-instance-of-has-no-member-for-class-with-dyn)

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135263/class-has-no-objects-member).  The gist is that it's a pylint problem not a django issue and you can solve by incorporating [pylint-django](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django).