# Pandas Data Frame is not correctly identified: Instance of 'tuple' has no 'filter' member

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a class containing pandas functionalities. As an input I have a pandas dataframe but python seems to not recognizing it right.

```
import pandas as pd

class box:
    def __init__(self, dataFrame, pers, limit):
        self.df = dataFrame,
        self.pers = pers,
        self.data = limit

    def cleanDataset(self):
        persDf = self.df.filter(regex=('^' + self.pers + r'[1-9]$'))
        persDF.replace({'-': None})
```

self.df.filter(...) gives me the warning: `Instance of 'tuple' has no 'filter' member`. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990313/avoid-pylint-warning-e1101-instance-of-has-no-member-for-class-with-dyn) but cannot apply the solution though since the problem is not caused by django.

Anyone who can help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the comma at the end of `self.df = dataFrame,` (and `self.pers = pers,`).  The comma isn't necessary here.

The comma makes the class think you're defining `self.df` as a tuple with one member.  To check this, create a box object `b` and try `print type(box.df)`.  I'm guessing this will return `<type 'tuple'>`.

Remove the commas after the attribute definitions:

```
class box:
    def __init__(self, dataFrame, pers, limit):
        self.df = dataFrame
        self.pers = pers
        self.data = limit
```