# Pylint: Module/Instance of has no member for google.cloud.vision API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pylint, google-cloud-vision

When I run this code (which will later be used to detect and extract text using Google Vision API in Python) I get the following errors:

> Module 'google.cloud.vision_v1.types' has no 'Image' member pylint(no-member)
>
> Instance of 'ImageAnnotatorClient' has no 'text_detection' member pylint(no-member)

```py
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
import os, io

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r'C:\Users\paul\VisionAPI\key.json'
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

FILE_NAME = 'im3.jpg'
FOLDER_PATH = r'C:\Users\paul\VisionAPI\images'


with io.open(os.path.join(FOLDER_PATH , FILE_NAME), 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
response = client.text_detection(image=image)
```

What does "Module/Instance of ___ has no members" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the pylint error, though the script executes successfully when run (with minor modifications for my environment to change the filename being processed).

Therefore, I am assuming that by "run this code" you mean "run this code through pylint".  If not, please update the question with how you are executing the code in a way that generates pylint errors.

[This page](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:e1101) describes the specific error you are seeing, and the case that causes a false positive for it.  This is likely exactly the false positive you are hitting.

The Google Cloud Vision module appears to dynamically create these members, and pylint doesn't have a way to detect that they actually exist at runtime, so it raises the error.

Two options:

- Tag the affected lines with a `# pylint: disable=no-member` annotation, as suggested in the page linked above.
- Run pylint with the `--ignore-modules=google.cloud.vision_v1` flag (or put the equivalent in your .pylintrc).  You'll notice that even the actual module name is different than the one you imported :)

This is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990313/avoid-pylint-warning-e1101-instance-of-has-no-member-for-class-with-dyn) with more detail about workarounds for the E1101 error.