# Boto3 Instance of '' has no 'Bucket'

Tags: python, boto3

Getting the error "Instance of '' has no 'Bucket' memberpylint(no-member)"

Tried without my profile and with a profile. No difference.

```
BUCKET = 'mybucket'

import boto3

dev = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='dev')

s3 = dev.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET)
```

Error for linting is on the `s3.Bucket line`

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35990313/5028532

Comment: Thanks, I'll add the line `# pylint: disable=E1101` and give it a go